# How to retain values of select box after search when select box have 2 names?

Tags: php

[image][image]I have php page for vehicle search filters which is connected to database. In this page i used 1 field select box to select age of driver which is 21-24 and 25+ and create 2 columns in database which is driver_age for 21-24 and driverage for 25+ because some vehicles are available for both age of drivers.. So i only want that when i select values from all field and click on search button then values in the field remains same so user know what they searched but i got problem in driver age field as it have 2 columns in database ..ALso please check my code below..

```
$('#driver').change(function() {
  if($('#driver option:selected').val() == '21-24') {
    $('#driver').attr('name','driverage');
  }
  if($('#driver option:selected').val() == '25+') {
    $('#driver').attr('name','driver_age');
  }
});

<select class="half" id="driver" name="driverage" >
  <option value="21-24">21-24</option>
  <option value="25+">25+</option>        
</select>
```

[database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEfzZ.png)

[FRont end screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/563VJ.png)

Comment: "2 columns in database which is driver_age for 21-24 and driverage for 25+". This sounds like it's crying out for normalisation, possibly into a many-to-many relationship. Also we can't see your query, which is the thing you seem to be having a problem with, so we can't easily fix that.

Comment: @Abhishek Vyas I only want to keep selected values in the field after click on search button as for now when i select 25+ and click on search it goes back to 21-24

Comment: it means your condition is not working

Comment: @ ADyson Yes i used some thing like this     <option value="21-24" <?php if(@$_REQUEST['driverage'] == '21-24'){?>selected<?php }?>>21-24</option>
    <option value="25+" <?php if(@$_REQUEST['driver_age'] == '25+'){?>selected<?php }?>>25+</option>

Comment: you should use `$_REQUEST['driverage']` for both lines - they are both possible values from the same field. There's no such thing as `driver_age` in your request. Well, actually right now there possibly is, because you use some JavaScript to change the name attribute. But that's completely pointless, there is no need for it. Remove the Javascript and change the PHP as I suggested. Only one of the `ifs` can ever be true at once so that part should work then. But your database structure I would still recommend you to analyse and study how it can be normalised properly.

Comment: @ADyson  ok thanks